# jq: not using environment variable correctly

Tags: environment-variables, jq

I have an `envs.json` file with content:

```
{ 
  "dev-cc1": { "url": "https://my-url.com" }, 
  "dev-cc2": { "url": "https://my-url.com" }
}
```

I would like to fetch urls based on an environment variable `$ENV`, but every other related article I came across didn't seem to work, or I just read it wrong. I think I'm missing something super trivial...

Things I tried:

```
export ENV="dev-cc1"
jq --arg ENV "$ENV" -n '."env.ENV"' envs.json
```

Because my env variable has a dash in it, I quoted around it, and then tried to reference it inside. However jq returns back `null`.

The hardcoded query works (`jq --arg ENV "$ENV" '."dev-cc1"' envs.json`), and I've also confirmed that the environment variable is passed in correctly `jq --arg ENV "$ENV" -n 'env.ENV'`.

I tried a ton of different ways to substitute this env var in but none worked.. Could anyone please give this a second pair of eyes?

Comment: `jq --arg ENV "$ENV" '.[$ENV]' envs.json`? The `-n` doesn't make sense, and `.env` isn't required either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
ENV="dev-cc1" jq '.[env.ENV]' envs.json
```

or

```
export ENV="dev-cc1"
jq '.[env.ENV]' envs.json
```

or using a jq variable:

```
ENV="dev-cc1"
jq --arg ENV "$ENV" '.[$ENV]' envs.json
```

Comment: These worked, I was missing the square brackets... thank you!

Comment: Didn't work for me... $ ENV="dev-cc1" jq --arg ENV "$ENV" '.[$ENV]' a.json | cat a.json... prints empty

Comment: @MarcellodeSales It's `ENV="dev-cc1"; jq --arg ENV "$ENV" '.[$ENV]' a.json`.

Comment: @Freddy not working for me... `ENV="dev-cc1"; jq --arg ENV "$ENV" '.[$ENV]' a.json | cat a.json | wc -l
       0`

Comment: I'm using `jq-1.6` on a MacOS... Found this issue is related to my problem https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/405#issuecomment-546611020

Comment: @Freddy I can use the env value filter things, but not to write to files

Comment: Piping the output to `cat a.json` doesn't make sense.